Postgresql command not finbished in NODEJS app
I have issue with adding record on postgresql via nodejs
Here is code snippet :
async createOrder(orderParams: CreateOrderParams): Promise<any> {
        await this.initConnection();
        let  insertCommand = `my insert query  `;  //works on Postgresql shell

        
        try { 
            const result = await this.pgClient.query(insertCommand);
            console.log(`Total rows inserted : ${result.rowCount}`);
            await this.pgClient.end();
        }
        catch(Err) { 
            console.log(Err);
        }
        
        return;

    }
    
  async initConnection() : Promise<any> {
        this.pgClient = await new Client(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
        if (this.pgClient) { 
            console.log('Connection created');
        }  
    }

When  arriving to string with executing query  - the promise does not resolved and no exception
Here is connection string :
DATABASE_URL = postgresql://michael_test:<mypwd>@mytestcluster-2740.jxf.gcp-europe-west1.cockroachlabs.cloud:26257/defaultdb?sslmode=verify-full

I am using pg npm package
What can cause to such issue ( I know there are similar questions - tried several options )
Thanks in advance

Try running a test on a local PostgreSQL instance and monitor the log file, or if you have access to your server monitor there the log file.
